# directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/../Developer/Library/Frameworks' ld: file not found:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm not sure why but all the sudden my project fails to build and shows:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: file not found: /Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/inline-ios-axberuiwgueuitfzxttaoekgigob/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp-ios.app/my-app
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how can I investigate this?

I recently deleted a file from the tests folder

and the bundle id was changed a day ago

**Update**

I saw an answer in another thread in SO, saying to delete anything under framework search path.

but mine was empty already

Comment: Confirm which target this happened. I too had an empty framework search path on my main target, but didn't notice that the error was actually happening on my tests target. When I went to my tests target, I found that the framework search path for that target was not blank...

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to check all of your targets.  My main app target had the `Framework Search Path` already empty and still had this issue as well.

I found a Github issue for a project having this issue and they solved it by removing a test (or test file maybe).  I checked my test target and found that it did have the {SDK-ROOT} path in there still.  I deleted it, and the warning went away.